# python error code handling

Tags: python, subprocess, error-code

I want to check what distribution is installed:

```
def check_linux():
    if subprocess.call(['apt-get', '-v']) == 0: #if true
        print('apt')
    else:                                       #if false
        print('rpm')

check_linux()
print('done')
```

When I try this at debian distro every thing is OK I got:
"apt" and "done" at stdout. But if I run this code at fedora there is error code and "done" is not printing (script ends too early).
How to fix this ?

Comment: try some `try/except`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `try/except`. With this method, you would simply `try` to run `apt`. If this does not work (i.e.--`except`) try to run `rpm`. If neither of these work, then I suggest defaulting to what Bereal suggested--use the default `platform.linux_distribution`.
However, since it is very likely that at least one of these are installed, I think you are better off with the `try` method. Furthermore, you can later include packages such as `yum`, etc. 
Sample code for `try/except` (general):

```
try:
    x = input("Please input a number.\n")
except ValueError: # Someone put in a character
    print 'Not a valid number.\n'
```

In your scenario:

```
import os
package_manager = ""
def check_linux():
    try:
        os.system("apt")
        package_manager = "apt"
    except:
        os.system("rpm")
        package_manager = "rpm"
    except: # WARNING! NEVER USE EXCEPT WITHOUT AN ERROR EXCEPT IN THE SIMPLEST OF SCENARIOS. When I find the correct error for this situation I will edit my code.
        os.sytem("yum")# ...etc, etc.
        package_manager = "yum"
    print package_manager

check_linux()
print 'done'
```

Happy coding! and best of luck!

Comment: `try..except..except` is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: @bereal i know, but i don't know what the error is. you can have multiple excepts if you have multiple errors that are different.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.call` raises an exception if it cannot find the executable to run, which is the case for Fedora and `apt-get`. You could traverse the `PATH` or try any other common tricks, but luckily Python already has the function [platform.linux_distribution()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution) in its standard library, for example:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('CentOS Linux', '7.0.1406', 'Core')
```

You can check how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/platform.py#L298).